# I want a code for 6 LDR/LED pair

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, led

Each LDR is connected to one LED because I am doing a parking lot model. I have tried but with no luck. Help!

```
    int ledPin = 11;
int sensorInput = A0;

boolean ledIsOn = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int lightLevel = analogRead(A0);

  if (ledIsOn) {
    if (lightLevel > 600) {
      ledIsOn = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (lightLevel < 400) {
      ledIsOn = true;
    }
  }

  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledIsOn);

  Serial.println(lightLevel);
}
```

*this is the code for one LED to one LDR Sensor but I cannot make the 6 led to 6 ldr

and I did this code for 6 LDR

```
#define pin_size 6
const int pin[pin_size] = { A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < pin_size; i++) {
    Serial.print(analogRead(pin[i]));
    Serial.print(" - ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("  |  ");

  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. Please be aware that this is not a free design house or an on-demand online technical encyclopedia. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: `I have tried` ... please show the work that you have done .... do you have a question? ... you have  not asked anything.

Comment: When you want to have the same thing happen multiple times with multiple settings or values it can be useful to generalise it by creating a class, then instantiating one object per LED + LDR pair.

Comment: can u explain more?

Comment: you posted working code for one LDR/LED pair .... please post the code that does not work

Comment: this is the code for one LED to one LDR Sensor but I cannot make the 6 led to 6 ldr

Comment: note: you do not need this statement `if (ledIsOn) {`  ..... only two lines `if (lightLevel > 600)  ledIsOn = false;` and `if (lightLevel < 400)  ledIsOn = true;`

Comment: ok can you please help me with the 6 LDR and 6 LED code I cannot seem to be able to do it

Comment: use `lightLevel_1`, `ledIsOn_1`, `lightLevel_2`, `ledIsOn_2`, `lightLevel_3`, `ledIsOn_3`, etc.

Comment: `I cannot seem to be able to do it` ... you still have not posted your code that you tried, but that does not work as expected

Comment: I edited my post now

Comment: I have the code for 6 LDR but I don't know how to make the code with 6 ldr and 6 led

Comment: does that code print out the values from the 6 LDRs? ..... do your comparison inside the `for` loop .... add code that uses `lightLevel[i]` and `ledIsOn[i]`

Comment: this code is just for 6 LDR and I need to add on it 6 led because my project is to create 6 LDR/LED pair

Comment: can you just please help me with the codes

Comment: Do you really understand, what the code for 1 LDR/LED pair does exactly? It doesn't seem so. You already created a `for` loop, that iterates through all the analog inputs. Now create an array with the LEDs pin numbers like you did with the analog pins. Inside the `for` loop, do what you have done before with 1 LDR/LED pair: Read the analog value into a variable, check if the variable is above `600` or below `400` and use `digitalWrite()` with the corresponding pin number (from the array) to set the correct value. If you cannot do this, you haven't understood, what the original code does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert all the regular variables to arrays. The loop through each index and run the the same as before for each index.

```
const int pin_size 6
int ledPins[] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int sensorPins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
boolean ledIsOn[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < pin_size; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < pin_size; i++) {
    int lightLevel = analogRead(sensorPins[i]);

    if (ledIsOn[i]) {
      if (lightLevel > 600) {
        ledIsOn[i] = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (lightLevel < 400) {
        ledIsOn[i] = true;
      }
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], ledIsOn[i]);

    Serial.println(lightLevel);
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems that you may have done the OP's school assignment.

Comment: @jsotola I wasn’t really convinced, and gave it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: you may be correct in your thinking .... i do not mean to put down your choice to answer, i just wonder if the OP learned anything